# Get DB2 instance name using SQL

Tags: db2, metadata, db2-luw

Is it possible to find the instance name of a DB2 database by querying the catalog metadata? For instance, we can find the columns of tables using `SELECT tbname, column_name FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS`. Is there an analogous query that can get the instance name?

I need this because I am running a query to get the remaining free space in the DB, across several instances. I would prefer to have the query itself tell me the name of the instance.

Running DB2 10.5 on Linux.

Comment: What Db2 platform/version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For DB2 LUW you can use [`ENV_INST_INFO`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022040.html?pos=2). The instance name is in the column `INST_NAME`:

```
SELECT INST_NAME FROM SYSIBMADM.ENV_INST_INFO
```

Comment: `select inst_name FROM sysibmadm.env_inst_info` returns a name I recognize, but not the one I need. Let's say my JDBC URL is `jdbc:db2://hostname.company.com:portNumber/InstanceName`. I need the InstanceName. The INST_NAME returned above is a name I can see in the IDE (IBM Data Studio) at "level 2 in the tree". (Sorry - don't know what to call it.) The InstanceName I want is at level 3 in the tree.

Comment: You don't connect to an instance, but to a database.

Comment: In that case, I want the database name, because the instance name is the same across all our environments.

Comment: Mark this as answered and ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DB2-server version and platform, you might use MON_GET_INSTANCE table function (see IBM DB2 knowledge center for details and example).   For the instance name you can  use PDLOGMSGS_LAST24HOURS

Comment: The documentation does not seem to say that the instance name is returned. Also, I don't have the privileges to run that function, so I cannot confirm or disprove your statement. Thank you for answering, though. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0060770.html

Comment: See also PDLOGMSGS_LAST24HOURS (returns column INSTANCENAME)

Comment: `select * FROM sysibmadm.pdlogmsgs_last24hours` runs, but returns nothing for my DB