# SQL Query to Get DB2 Version on IBM i

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to find out which version of DB2 we are running on our IBM **i** server **using only SQL SELECT**.

I am executing my queries via installed ODBC drivers for i Access. The places I am executing the queries are Excel-ODBC and Excel-Microsoft Query (simply because I am not a developer and therefore don't have/don't know of another place to run queries).

The following solutions do not work for me:

[How to check db2 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821795/how-to-check-db2-version)

[Get DB2 instance name using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330968/get-db2-instance-name-using-sql)

Basic reasons why I have failed to get the above solutions to work:

1. I do not have a SYSPROC table/have access to SYSPROC table
2. SYSIBMADM table does not contain a ENV_INST_INFO table.
3. I think these answers may be tailored to those using IBM z, but I use IBM i.

My end goal is to be able to execute a SQL SELECT and get the version of DB2 used on our server.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT substring(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1, 8) FROM qsys2.data_area_info
WHERE data_area_library = 'QUSRSYS' and data_area_name = 'QSS1MRI' `

Comment: I get:

 "SQL0462 - Procedure or user-defined function OBJECT_STATISTICS in QSYS2 returned a warning SQLSTATE."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT RELEASE_LEVEL, TEXT_DESCRIPTION
FROM QSYS2.SOFTWARE_PRODUCT_INFO
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = '5770SS1' 
AND PRODUCT_OPTION = '27'
--or this instead of the above line:
--AND LOAD_TYPE = 'CODE' AND PRODUCT_OPTION = '*BASE'
```

Comment: When I tried your alternate version (AND LOAD_TYPE) It did return values, but it was the IBM i version. The DB2 version is different I believe (but I really do not fully understand the difference).

Still, yours is the only answer that yielded a query that actually returned a value.

Comment: [IBM i database frequently asked questions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=troubleshooting-i-database-faq): *What level of Db2 for i do I have?* 
If you are using a IBM i product, you have Db2 for i. The level of Db2 for i is based on the IBM i operating system and is independent of the DB2 versioning scheme. **Because Db2 for i is included with the IBM i operating system, the version, release, and modification level of Db2 for i is the same as that of your operating system.**